# Responsive iframes height with Bootstrap CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap's CSS technique for making responsive iframes; Wrapping the iframe with `.embed-responsive` CSS Class, along with `.embed-responsive-21by9` to specify the aspect ratio. (Basically adding `position: absolute;` for the iframe and `padding-top: 42.857143%;` for the iframe wrapper.

This works very well with videos, but not with other iframes such as a Twitter tweet (in which the iframe has larger width than the height), leaving an empty vertical space.

What are the solutions to overcome this, considering I'm using WordPress theme which automatically wraps all the iframes in my content with a predfined CSS Class, `.embed-responsive .embed-responsive-21by9` in mycase.

Comment: When you inspect the element to you see any extra CSS that's causing this behavior?

Comment: No, it's just a fixed height for the wrapper. The iframe itself could have a small height leaving an empty vertical space.

Comment: So you're saying is it isn't filling the iFrame completely, not the outside part of the CSS

Comment: Yup. Because the iframe itself is short.